# How to use python to operate SAP Gui and run SAP Scripts?

Tags: python-3.x

As a officer of SAP MM, I want to code an application to do some duplicate work. But when I record SAP Gui Script, I could not run it successfully in Python. Did I use the wrong Module or something wrong with my code?

```
import win32com.client
import sys

def SAP_OP():
    excelPath = r'#'
    SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI")
    if not type(SapGuiAuto) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
        return

    application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    if not type(application) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
        SapGuiAuto = None
        return

    connection = application.Children(0)
    if not type(connection) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
        application = None
        SapGuiAuto = None
        return

    session = connection.Children(0)
    if not type(session) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
        connection = None
        application = None
        SapGuiAuto = None
        return

    session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/nMM03"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_VKORG-LOW").text = "#"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_VTWEG-LOW").text = "#"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtP_EKORG").text = "#"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_WERKS-LOW").text = "#"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_WERKS-LOW").setFocus
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_WERKS-LOW").caretPosition = 4
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press()
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlMAT_CONT/shellcont/shell").currentCellColumn = r"#"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlMAT_CONT/shellcont/shell").contextMenu
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlMAT_CONT/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem = r"&XXL"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press()
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press()
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press()
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press()

    session = None
    connection = None
    application = None
    SapGuiAuto = None

SAP_OP()
```

Comment: I have used win32com module, whether I need to change the module?

Comment: Is It a complex question?LOL

Comment: It seems that there is still no specific module to solve.

Comment: excuse me. what tools do you use inspect "wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_VKORG-LOW"

Answer (score 6):

Try the below it should work. Change the ConnectionName, Username and Password according to your credential.

```
# Importing the Libraries
import win32com.client
import sys
import subprocess
import time


# This function will Login to SAP from the SAP Logon window

def saplogin():

    try:

        path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe"
        subprocess.Popen(path)
        time.sleep(10)

        SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject('SAPGUI')
        if not type(SapGuiAuto) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
            return

        application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
        if not type(application) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
            SapGuiAuto = None
            return
        connection = application.OpenConnection("ConnectionName", True)

        if not type(connection) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
            application = None
            SapGuiAuto = None
            return

        session = connection.Children(0)
        if not type(session) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
            connection = None
            application = None
            SapGuiAuto = None
            return

        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").text = "USERNAME"
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").text = "PASSWORD"
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)

    except:
        print(sys.exc_info()[0])

    finally:
        session = None
        connection = None
        application = None
        SapGuiAuto = None


saplogin()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. And I found a tool named Scripting Tracker, which can automatically generate the specific codes.

Comment: <class 'pywintypes.com_error'> any solution for this one?

Comment: Check my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66367542/9329965