# Unable to identify items in child window of SAP application using pywinauto and inspect.exe

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

I am trying to login to an SAP application using pywinauto to automate daily tasks? I am unable to find the properties to enter the username and password?

I have launched the application and tried to check for the control identifiers that would help me enter the user name and password.

```py
import win32com.client
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto import Desktop
from time import sleep
import subprocess

sap_path='C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe'
username = 'abcdefg'
password='c12345#'
subprocess.Popen([sap_path])
sleep(30)
dlg=Desktop(backend='uia').window(title_re='SAP Logon',top_level_only = True)
dlg.log_on.invoke()
dlg.wait('ready', timeout=60)
print(dlg.print_control_identifiers(depth=2))
```

It does not give me any identifier for the child window that reflects. I tried using inspect.exe to find the elements i am unable to do so.

Comment: SAP GUI has its own scripting engine.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov does python have any module for the same to access the parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use python to operate SAP Gui and run SAP Scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54086565/how-to-use-python-to-operate-sap-gui-and-run-sap-scripts)

Comment: https://answers.sap.com/questions/615354/sap-gui-library-in-python.html

Comment: https://blogs.sap.com/2012/10/08/introduction-to-sap-gui-scripting/

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Thanks for the links. IT does not work for me. Coz i get this error.<class 'pywintypes.com_error'>

Comment: Maybe the latest version of COM interface for SAP was changed. I'm not familiar with SAP GUI.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Thank you for the help and research to help me get started. I am not sure why it does not work. Thanks again.