# Post a text into a Textfield in a random Windows App using Python

Tags: python-3.x, automation, pyautogui

I'm trying to send a text value into form in SAP (Form window is always open). I need a library that allows me to select a specific window and send keys into a FormField in this window.

I read about Pywinauto but I don't think it has the functionality.

Comment: SAP is a software company. What software are you talking about?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use python to operate SAP Gui and run SAP Scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54086565/how-to-use-python-to-operate-sap-gui-and-run-sap-scripts)